# Crash on BizHawk using a short LUA script

Tags: lua

when using this very short script on the lua console on BizHawk (it's an emulator), Both the LUA console and BizHawk crashes at the same time.
I'd like to know if the error comes from my script or from BizHawk, her's the script: (What it is supposed to do is check if the player is not moving for a certain time  period [TimeoutConstant] and if he is [cause he's dead, stuck or afk] the script loads a saved state called Filename and it starts again. Here's the script:

```
Filename = "yolo.state"
TimeoutConstant = 80
rightmost = 0
timeout = TimeoutConstant

function initializeRun()
    savestate.load(Filename)
    rightmost = 0
    timeout = TimeoutConstant
end

function getPositions()
    marioX = memory.read_s16_le(0x94)
    marioY = memory.read_s16_le(0x96)

    local layer1x = memory.read_s16_le(0x1A);
    local layer1y = memory.read_s16_le(0x1C);

    screenX = marioX-layer1x
    screenY = marioY-layer1y
end

initializeRun()

while true do
    getPositions()

    if marioX > rightmost then
        rightmost = marioX
        timeout = TimeoutConstant
    end

    if timeout <= 0 then
        initializeRun()
    end 

    timeout = timeout - 1
end
```

Comment: Would be really great if you could include the code in the question, not as a picture.

Comment: Her's a patebin link: http://pastebin.com/mSw35diM

Answer (score 0):

I assume by "crash" you mean "freeze" which is not at all the same thing. It's freezing because your script is putting the emulator into a busy loop. You didn't do anything to advance time in the emulator. The final two lines of your script need to be:

```
emu.frameadvance();
end
```

BTW, with emulator lua scripts, the name of the game being scripted is essential information.